# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'SCNNode' ARKit

Tags: swift, uikit, arkit

```
//ARFace geometry update
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
              let contentController = faceAnchorAndContentControllers[faceAnchor],
              let contentNode = contentController.contentNode else {
            return
        }
```

Getting same problem. What should I change here?

Can someone explain where is my mistake?

Comment: Break up the guard something in there isn’t optional so it doesn’t need guard

Answer (score -2):

May be `faceAnchorAndContentControllers[faceAnchor]` dictionary is not returning the optional `SCNNode`. You need to modify your code little bit as follows:

```
struct Controller{
    let contentNode: SCNNode?
}

 var faceAnchorAndContentControllers : [ARFaceAnchor : Controller] = [:]

 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
          let contentController = faceAnchorAndContentControllers[faceAnchor],
          let contentNode = contentController.contentNode else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Making something optional only to satisfy code that incorrectly assumed it was an optional is not helpful (you're making it worse). The logical solution would be to move the non-optional outside the guard clause.